# Error with dependencies for a project in angular

Tags: angular, dependencies, npm-install, package.json

I have a problem with a proyect that I'm trying to update from angular 8 to 16. First of all I modify my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^16.0.4",
    "@types/angular-material": "^1.1.73",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "angular-notifier": "^14.0.0",
    "config": "^3.3.9",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.4.0",
    "express-http-context": "^1.2.4",
    "lamejs": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.7.1",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^9.1.5",
    "notiflix": "^3.2.6",
    "winston": "^3.9.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/language-service": "~16.0.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "~20.2.5",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.0.2"
  }
```

Every time I make a 'npm i' with that dependencies I get a lot of errors of compabilities
[Don't know why I always get a lot of errors like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jZPF.png)

Anyone knows how to solve that problem? Thanks.

I try to make a NPM install with a package json of an angular proyect. And I expect don't get errors while installing dependencies.

Comment: As a quick workaround, you can try the command "npm install --force". If you put the complete error screenshot, it would be helpful to check the error message clearly.

Comment: It's ideally recommended to migrate incrementally. I'd suggest that you migrate from 8 to 9, 9 to 10 and so on and so forth.